# What design pattern can be applied to build an object that requires data from two datareaders?

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns

I'm a novice programmer interested in learning about "Design Patterns".  I've read a lot of information regarding design patterns from multiple sites but most utilize very basic applications of a particular pattern.

My goal is to compose an object that has data from multiple tables. I'm using the repository pattern to extract the required data from one table in my db.  But I also need additional data from a second table. (Using Joins in my opinion would complicate this unnecessarily) This is where I'm not sure what to do next.  Would the Factory Patterns be best? Etc...

For the most part at least some guidance as to how to do this would be helpful and not necessarily actual "code".

Comment: Could you show code for more detail?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify why you don't want to use a join? If a query using a join would return the data you need as a single result set then presumably that would make your client code simpler?

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that you already got the answer figured out. You said "compose" in your question. [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design pattern focuses on constructing a complex object step by step and it almost always builds a Composite

Comment: @Arun Ok, I'm going back on my word here but now I'm interested to see how you would apply this in sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how constructive this will be, but what I would do would be to get two objects and compose the third from the two parts.

```
MyObjectA a = GetFromDataReader1();
MyObjectB b = GetFromDatareader1();
MyCompositeObject c = MyCompositeObject.FromParts(a,b);

class MyCompositeObject
{
 // all your properties you need
  public static MyCompositeObject FromParts(MyObjectA a, MyObjectB b) 
  { //return a new MyCompositeObject here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a DataMapper-type pattern ( http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html ).

This pattern works well with a Repository as the repository can compose and execute the queries, while the datamappers take the results (datareader) and build the relevant objects.

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html